# Magento addError redirects to login screen

Tags: php, magento

I'm creating a Magento module, and I've created a setup resource model that checks if a folder is writable. If yes; it creates a folder, otherwise it displays an error message. The problem is, that when using addError, it redirects to the admin login screen and displays the message there. It doesn't log out though. When reloading the page it ends up where you were before the setup was ran.

```
class Blabla_Bleh_Model_Resource_Setup extends Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup {
    function createImportFolder() {
        $baseDir = Mage::getBaseDir();
        $importDir = $baseDir.DS.'var'.DS.'import';
        $dir = $importDir.DS.'blabladir';
        $io = new Varien_Io_File();
        $errorMessage = Mage::helper('blabla_bleh')->__('Errormessage...');

        if($io->isWriteable($importDir)) {
            $io->checkAndCreateFolder($dir);
        } else {
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($errorMessage);
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following statement after redirect,

```
 return;
```

Comment: Thanks, but same result

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using wrong class of session.Try core session for this :

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError($errorMessage);
```

Comment: Thanks, but the result is the same.

Comment: try to redirect to previous url ?

Comment: I tried that as per the answer from @Pravin, but the redirect acts a bit werid and the error is gone missing.

Answer (score 0):

Use following code to redirect

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError('Error message to be here');
$this->_redirect('*/*/controllerActionmethod');
```

Hope this help

Comment: Thanks, but `$this->_redirect` does not work here. I tried `$reDirect = Mage::helper('adminhtml')->getUrl('adminhtml/mobile');` (mobile just to try something to redirect to) `Mage::app()->getResponse()->setRedirect($reDirect);` but it is redirecting to the dashboard despite the URL target is 'mobile' when echoing and copy/pasting it, and the error message is missing. I tried `session_write_close();` before the redirect as I read that could be a solution, but same result there - no error message is displayed.

Comment: Oh! Your class inherits Resource_Setup class of Magento. hence you will not get $this->_redirects. You have to return somethings from your method `createImportFolder()`. Please refer `function _modifyResourceDb` in file `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php`. Hope this help

Comment: try to use try catch like `try{ \\your code} catch (Exception $e) {
                printf('<pre>%s</pre>', print_r($e, true));
                throw Mage::exception('Mage_Core', Mage::helper('core')->__('Error in file: "%s" - %s', $fileName, $e->getMessage()));
            }`

Comment: Thanks, no luck though. When throwing an exception I just get the ugly white page with Mage_Core_Exception Object, if developer mode is off I get the error page (not the error message). Also tried to return something from the method and do the error check from "outside" but no change. It seems to work differently when doing things from within setup scripts. I think I'll just give up for now - and come back for this when the module is finished.